# My classification report always fails to show me the accuracy parameter. How do i fix that?

Tags: python

```
              precision-recall  f1-score   support

     class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
     class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
     class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3

   micro avg       0.60      0.60      0.60         5
   macro avg       0.50      0.56      0.49         5
weighted avg       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```

No accuracy parameter is shown.

Comment: You need to provide more details in your question. How do you generate your report?

Answer (score -1):

The Micro average F1 and macro average F1 are same for binary or multi-class classification, hence, you can consider micro average F1 as accuracy, which is 0.60 or 60% in your case.

However, if you are looking for something else, it can still be computed as:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
```